# How to take number values from a String, and convert them to int using a for loop?

Tags: java

I want to create a loop that will take the String values and convert them into int values.
Here is an example String `2012.12.31`
What I want is to kill loop once it get's to the "."
We will assume that all strings will contain only 2 "." in them.  Here is what I started with, and I am stuck.  Can some one guide me to what can be used?
I am a java learner, so I don't even know all the system commands that can be used in this case.  Here is how i wanted to go through with it.

```
DateSettings (String A){
    int YYYY, MM, DD;

    for (int i=0; i<A.indexOf('.'); i++);{
        YYYY = A[i];
    }

}
```

Comment: This semicolon after `for` loop paranthesis will be painful ;)

Comment: @gonczor actually, this would not compile because the variable `i` is use outside the scope of the loop ;) (without mention the usage of `[]` on a `String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with [`String.split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

```
String s = "2012.12.31";
String array[] = s.split("\\.");
int year = Integer.parseInt(array[0]);
//and so on
```

Also, there is a `;` after your loop, which probably causes the problem, along with the fact that you aren't updating the String

Comment: As said in comment, the `;` would prevent the code from compiling since `i` will not exist in that block statement

Comment: Thanks for the help, this answer seems like the best one, since it's simple and does not require a loop cheers

Answer (score 1):

There is a class (`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`) that parses the string date for you.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class StringToDateExample1 {

  public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
    String sDate1="2016.12.31";

    Date date1=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd").parse(sDate1);
    Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance();
    instance.setTime(date1);
    System.out.println("Year: " +instance.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    System.out.println("Month: " +(instance.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1));
    System.out.println("Day: " +instance.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
  }
}
```

This outputs:

```
Year: 2016
Month: 12
Day: 31
```

Another solution is use `Pattern.compile("\\.")`

```
List<Integer> collect = Pattern.compile("\\.")
   .splitAsStream(sDate1)
   .map(Integer::parseInt)
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: OP's format is specifically with a period `.` so I wan't sure if there is a format using that...

Comment: @ItamarGreen Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Correct, don't really answer the question but this is of course the simplest solution ;)

Comment: @AxelH Thanks, I was thinking the same thing :)))  So I added another answer with `Pattern.compile("\\.")`

Comment: Well, the `split` is simpler for this case. And Stream are a bit scary I believe ;) I don't know those enough either, I am learning to use them more often. Here, have a + ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use substring:

```
String yearString = A.substring(0,A.indexOf('.'));
int yyyy = Integer.parseInt(yearString);//will error if the string isn't only numbers.
```